# Android: Browse audio playlist and open a M3U file from an app

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, playlist, m3u

I am trying to find a way to browse audio playlist and return and save the Uri
of the playlist to play it later.

Like an alarm clock which you can select the playlist to paly it later when alarm
starts.

It is possible to get one song's URI, with intent but it doesn't work on playlist.

I have tried the intent,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
i.setType(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivity(i);
```

but it doesn't return URI, it runs MediaPlayback activity directly.

Any idea on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` instead of `Intent.ACTION_PICK`, and using `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have tried it but I get "no application can perform this action" error. Do you think that is it becasue I am running it on emulator? have you tried it on emulator?

Comment: I haven't personally used a playlist intent, just individual mp3's. However, take a look at this [forum topic](http://www.androiddiscuss.com/1-android-discuss/29092.html). It has some code that supposedly works for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that should work for playlists:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName
("com.android.music","com.android.music.PlaylistBrowserActivity"));
intent.setType(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.CONTENT_TYPE);
intent.setFlags(0x10000000);
intent.putExtra("oneshot", false);
intent.putExtra("playlist", playlistid);
startActivity(intent);
```

and to retrieve the playlistid:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query
(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
null);
if (cursor != null) {
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
     playlistid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID));
     playList.add(playlist);
     } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     cursor.close();
 }
}
```

(copied from http://www.androiddiscuss.com/1-android-discuss/29092.html)