# com.android.music.PlaylistBrowserActivity

Tags: java, android

In this post: [Android: Browse audio playlist and open a M3U file from an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161054/android-browse-audio-playlist-and-open-a-m3u-file-from-an-app)

you gave a very good answear. I still have some problem, can you help me?

The problem is:

`Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.music/com.android.music.PlaylistBrowserActivity};`

have you declared this activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

I tried to declear it in manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".playlist">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It says: `cannot resolve symbol 'playlist'`

I also tried:

```
<activity android:name="com.android.music">

    </activity>
```

It also says: `cannot resolve symbol 'music'`

Please help me if you can

Comment: is your activity name `playlist`?

Answer (score 0):

try this : it seems your `activity` name is `PlaylistBrowserActivity` not `playlist`.

```
<activity android:name="com.android.music.PlaylistBrowserActivity">

</activity>
```

OR

```
 <activity android:name=".PlaylistBrowserActivity">

  </activity>
```